# Android SQLite and Data storage Pros/Cons

Tags: android, database, sqlite

What is the best way for an app to push and pull data from an external database?

I want users of my app to be able to write to the database as well as view record data.

Would I use a SqLite database on a webserver somewhere? Does the database type make a difference?

Would an XML file work?

I am thinking that I can have data in my app. So, as users write new records, other users would be able to see those updates.

Suggestions? Comments? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use a local SQLite db on the android, that uses HTTPposts to interact with php on my webserver, which then accesses a mySQL instance.  Communication is done through serialized JSON objects as text, gzipped.  Transfers about 50kb of raw text as 10kb compressed, very manageable.

Theres lots of excellent tutorials here and otherwise, if you do a little googling for httppost android.

It is generally recommended NOT to have your mobile device have direct access to the online database, for better security and abstraction.  Besides php can do some great stuff like doubly validate inputs.

Comment: So, I can run a mysql database on a website, then use HTTPpost to allow the app to interact with the database.  Ok, Thanks for the info, I will do some more research. If I just want the app to access date, no two way communication, is this something I can just use SQLite? And have the data ship with the app? What would this do for app size?

Comment: It depends on your db size, even if its strictly accessing data.  If it's a query on millions of rows, youd probably best let a server do that heavy lifting (and heavy storage).  But assuming it is a smaller DB, a common approach would be to have it entirely as a SQLite in your application.  At periodic intervals (or perhaps through a "refresh data" button in your app) simply hit your webserver and redownload the entire thing, blowing away the old local copy in the process.

Comment: Ah..thanks...I went back and accepted answers. My initial app will be no more than say, 250 records, 4-6 fields. I have no idea how to make the data refresh, but I will check into that. Thanks again